# mobile scrolling not working for my website in Chrome developer tools

Tags: ios, scroll, inspector

Using Chrome version Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

1. In Chrome inspector (dev tools) my website (www.sbWebKids.com) doesn't scroll vertically. Without this feature working I cannot view anything below the fold on the the developer tools simulated iphone sizes.  Makes mobile development impossible with this tool.
2. There's also always been a discerning gap shown in the inspector mobile view, however I've tried the website on a dozen real phones (in a phone store) and there's no gap issue. See screenshot.

Screenshot here - http://alexwyrick.com/images/iphone5-and-chrome-screenshot.jpg

I've experienced this issue for months and possibly with another website or two, but never found a good solution.

Any ideas what the issue between my website and inspector could be?

Thank you for any feedback you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

On your body you've set...

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Try setting that to...

```
html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Because the only thing you're really worried about is the x-axis scrolling.

As for the gap on the right being caused by the inspector, I don't have an answer for that. Initially I thought it was the native Chrome scrollbar space; but it looks more like an inspected element colour.

Sorry I can't help with that second part >.<

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic explanation!